# Creating a cloze and the solution at once with help of conditions

Tags: presentations, exercises

I'm trying to make a `beamer` presentation for a lecture that also contains some small exercises. So I needed TeX to create a page where there are just the questions with room between each of them for the answers, followed by a page where the answers are included. Now the empty space should be just as large as the answer will be, for a nice look.

In addition I planned to give the presentation to the students some time before the lecture so they don't have to write down everything. Of course for this purpose I need a version of the presentation, where all the answers are left out.

I tried to create an environment using a boolean variable to specify whether the solutions should be printed or not. Now this would have helped to create an extra output for the students but would not have helped to hide the answer on one page and show it on the next.
Anyways, my attempts on doing so by using the `etoolbox` package didn't work at all.

I read about the package `exsheets` and hoped it could help me but only gave me an error that the file `tasks.sty` could not be found.

Has anybody experience with such problems?

Comment: when `tasks.sty` isn't found you have an outdated TeX distribution. It is part of both major distributions (first as part of the `exsheets` package) since October 2012, i.e., for nearly three years!

Comment: You may use some `\visible<...>{...}` macros (from beamer package).

Comment: @clemens Yes that might be true. Unfortunately I have no influence about the programs used on the computers at my workplace. We use a totally outdated version of debian as well :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need boolean switches, nor external tools; `beamer` offers you the functionality you need thorough its `modes` and `overlay` specifications.

Take a look at the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some questions}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{5cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First question\par
\onslide<2-|article:0>{First answer\par With two paragraphs}
\item Second question\par
\onslide<2-|article:0>{Second answer}
\end{enumerate}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces a two slide presentation: the first one showing the questions (with the space for the answers) and the second one with the questions and their answers:

[image]

Changing the preamble to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

you will now get an `article` document showing the questions, but not the answers:

[image]

Another option is to use the `handout` class option. Using

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some questions}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{5cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First question\par
\mode<beamer>{\onslide<2->{First answer\par With two paragraphs}}
\item Second question\par
\mode<beamer>{\onslide<2->{Second answer}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

will give the same result as the animation I included before (two slides: the first one with the questions and the space and the second one with questions and answers) and simply adding `handout` as class option, as in

```
\documentclass[handout]
```

{beamer}

now you have a one slide presentation just with the questions:

[image]

For further examples and examples, refer to the `beamer` user guide; search for `overlay` and read Section **21 Creating Handouts and Lecture Notes**.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was very informative. The version for the students doesn't look as intended right now, but you gave me a good basis I can work with :-)